# How to redirect and send data in getInitialProps in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

On index.js page I am fetching data that I would like all my pages has access to, but also depending on the data I receive, I want to redirect. How to redirect and pass data at the same time?

My code on _app.js

```
import "styles/globals.css";
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import getServiceAddress from "service/get-service-address";
import Router from "next/router";
export const MyContext= React.createContext({});

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, data, redirect }) {
  return (
      <MyContext.Provider value={data}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </MyContext.Provider>
  );
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
  if (context.ctx.pathname !== "/") { //if not index then do nothing
    return {};
  }

  const id= context.ctx.query.id;
  try {
    const url = `http://somepage.com/${id}`;

    const res = await axios.get(url);
    const data = res.data;

    if (data.hasSomeValue) {
       /// I want to redirect and send the data
      return {
        data: data,
        redirect: "/success",
      };
    }

    return { data };
  } catch (e) {
    return {
      redirect: "/error",
    };
  }
};

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: I see what you're trying to do but check out `next/router`. Instead of route sniffing / forwarding, you can actually see the pages and do your targeting.

Comment: You can't pass data that way. Either you pass the data in the query string when redirecting `/success?data=<your-data-as-string>` which has its limitation depending on the data you want to pass, or simply redirect and fetch the data on the target route.